# How to create a permutation array in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, permutation

I have a question about the permutation.
For example, I have the following table:

[image]

I want to make the permutation with this table. There are two options in the 1st column, three options in the 2nd and 3rd columns. The output permutation array should look like as follow:

[image]

There are 18 options to arrange the iterms in 1-3 columns. The question is how to use powershell to create a script to get such an array? And how to output this array into excel?

Comment: Is this an array of objects (are there column headers?) or an array of arrays (no column headers)?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, Yes, I forgot to put the headers. Column 1, column 2 and column 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, branching off of Joey's excellent answer, to iterate through an array with known columns you can do the following (PowerShell v3 or higher, it can be done in older versions but gets more complicated).

```
#clean up any existing variables
Remove-Variable array, alliterations -ea 4

#create the sample array
[array]$array += [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Column 1' = 'Single load'
    'Column 2' = 'MAT1'
    'Column 3' = 'Country A'
}
[array]$array += [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Column 1' = 'Uniform distributed load'
    'Column 2' = 'MAT2'
    'Column 3' = 'Country B'
}
[array]$array += [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Column 1' = ''
    'Column 2' = 'MAT3'
    'Column 3' = 'Country C'
}

#Create all iterations from that array
ForEach($a in ($array.'Column 1'|Where{$_})){

    ForEach($b in ($array.'Column 2'|Where{$_})){

        ForEach($c in ($array.'Column 3'|Where{$_})){
            [array]$AllIterations += [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Column 1' = $a
                'Column 2' = $b
                'Column 3' = $c
            }
        }
    }
}

#Display results
$AllIterations
```

That will generate the array:

```
Column 1                 Column 2 Column 3 
--------                 -------- -------- 
Single load              MAT1     Country A
Single load              MAT1     Country B
Single load              MAT1     Country C
Single load              MAT2     Country A
Single load              MAT2     Country B
Single load              MAT2     Country C
Single load              MAT3     Country A
Single load              MAT3     Country B
Single load              MAT3     Country C
Uniform distributed load MAT1     Country A
Uniform distributed load MAT1     Country B
Uniform distributed load MAT1     Country C
Uniform distributed load MAT2     Country A
Uniform distributed load MAT2     Country B
Uniform distributed load MAT2     Country C
Uniform distributed load MAT3     Country A
Uniform distributed load MAT3     Country B
Uniform distributed load MAT3     Country C
```

To get that into Excel you can either export to a CSV file as Joey suggested, or you can have PowerShell open Excel and paste the data into it directly.

```
#Copy array to clipboard as a tab delimited CSV
$AllIterations | ConvertTo-CSV -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInfo | Select -Skip 1 | Clip

#Open Excel, create a blank workbook, and paste the data in at cell A1
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WB = $XL.Workbooks.Add()
$XL.Visible = $true
$XL.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1).PasteSpecial()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with nested loops:

```
$(foreach ($a in 'Single Load','Uniform distributed load') {
  foreach ($b in 'MAT1','MAT2','MAT3') {
    foreach ($c in 'Country A','Country B','Country C') {
      New-Object -Prop @{Column1=$a;Column2=$b;Column3=$c}
    }
  }
}) | Export-Csv foo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The CSV file can then be opened by Excel.

Comment: It is a good method. However, I think I need a script that can do the permutation automatically. If I have a lot of data, it will take ages for me to type all the names.

Comment: Do you have another method that can solve a large amount of data? @joey

Comment: That's fine, you would just do `ForEach ($a in ($array.'Column 1'|Where{$_}))` and so on. If you don't pipe to `Where` it will iterate for the blank values as well.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: Was just thinking about how to solve this for arbitrary numbers of columns, which is a little trickier. I think the nicest approach I can think of would be generating code for `iex`.

Comment: Without working out all the details I would think that a function that calls itself for nesting purposes combined with `$array.psobject.properties.name` should allow you to iterate through any array regardless of the number of columns. If this is something that's wanted I can try and work out the code for it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician： Sorry, I do not understand what you suggested. Would you like to make a short script as an example, please?

Comment: Which suggestion? The first one, or the second one about the function?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: The first one. But I think the function is something I am looking for. Actually, I have a lot of data to deal with. A function could be easier to solve my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use the example in my question, I think the permutation function should do something like: there are three positions -A, B and C. For A, it picks one value from the first column; For B, it picks one value from the second column; For C, it picks one value from the third column. Position A has two options, position B and C have three options. The function will give the array of 18 combinations with an special order - A B C.    I hope this makes more sense.